# SQL statements while working with JSON file import

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

From a JSON file containing elements Id and Name, I want to fill my Directors table.

```
TABLE Director 
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(255) 
);
```

This way I retrieve the data from the JSON file, which works:

```
INSERT INTO Directors (Id, Name)
    SELECT Id, Name
    FROM OPENJSON(@DIRECTORS, '$')
         WITH (
            Id INT  '$.Id',
            Name VARCHAR(MAX) '$.Name'
         )
```

I don't want all the directors in this table, this is where the complexity comes around the corner. I have another table:

```
TABLE Movie 
(
    Id int,     
    Name varchar(255),    
    DirectorName varchar(255),     
    Genre varchar(255) 
);
```

Now, I want to only add the directors which have made a `Genre = 'Horror'` movie. I guess I've to do some matching with `DirectorName` and `Genre`, but I don't know how.

I tried, but this isn't working due to bad syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Directors (Id, Name)
    SELECT d.Id, d.Name
    FROM OPENJSON(@DIRECTORS, '$') as d
         WITH (
            Id INT  '$.Id',
            Name VARCHAR(MAX) '$.Name'
         )
         -- Something here which check if movie.Genre == Horror and d.name == 
        -- movie.Directorname
```

But I get a syntax error, which I don't know what's wrong.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: A join maybe? `JOIN Movie m ON m.DirectorName = d.Name AND m.Genre = 'Horror'` Although this is all kind of weird: how do you have `Movies` with directors which are not in the `Directors` table, do you not have foreign keys?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: OPENJSON(…) WITH ( …'$.Name') as d